# How can i get two values from async storage and then send them to fetch as parameters in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I'm trying to retrieve two values from async storage and then immediately send the values as parameters of the fetch url, however i keep getting this error **[Error: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.]**

```
const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const [code, setCode] = useState('');
  const [city, setCity] = useState('');
  //
  useEffect(() => {
    const getData = async () => {
      try {
        setCity(await AsyncStorage.getItem('city'));
        setCode(await AsyncStorage.getItem('code'));
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
    };
    getData();
  }, []);
  //
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('Fetching prices');
    if (data.length == 0) {
      // Only make the fetch request if data is null
      const fetchData = async () => {
        try {
          const response = await fetch(
            `apiurlhere/${city}/${code}`
          );
          const data = await response.json();
          setData(data);
          setLoading(false);
        } catch (error) {
          console.log(error);
        }
      };
      fetchData();
    }
  }, [city, code, data]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to set `AsyncStorage` items to the state, just get them when executing `fetch`. Something like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
  console.log('Fetching prices');
  if (data.length == 0) {
    // Only make the fetch request if data is null
    const fetchData = async () => {
      try {
        const city = await AsyncStorage.getItem('city');
        const code = await AsyncStorage.getItem('code');
        const response = await fetch(
          `apiurlhere/${city}/${code}`
        );
        const data = await response.json();
        setData(data);
        setLoading(false);
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
    };
    fetchData();
  }
}, [data]);
```

Comment: I set them to state because I have to show those values somewhere in the page as well